# What is the best way to generate "static" js in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a javascript file which is generated by simple ruby-script and saved in public/js/ dir. It's working, but i want to use something like assets pipeline (ye, i know there are few for sinatra), so this file will be generated after each deployment.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gem may work for you

https://github.com/kalasjocke/sinatra-asset-pipeline

Other wise, feel free to use a few gems that does the job here

http://mutelight.org/asset-pipeline

Comment: But it seems like they can generate js code only with inbuild compilers (like uglifier or closure), but not via my own ruby script.

Comment: I would just bite the bullet and ditch the custom JS builder. Yeah, you can add code to your init script, which would compile the JS every time you restart the web server. But that does not help if you are debugging code, since it would not auto refresh on save.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably want to use git hooks in combination with a rake task. Take a look at: http://jimneath.org/2012/05/05/precompile-assets-using-a-git-hook.html